# Twitter Account Activity API - 'code': 214, 'message': 'Non-200 response code during CRC GET request (i.e. 404, 500, etc).'

Tags: python, tweepy, pythonanywhere, twitterapi-python

I was using a sample app, that manages Tweeter Account Activity API, here's the link:

https://github.com/RickRedSix/twitter-webhook-boilerplate-python/blob/master/Main.py

I built my web app in pythonanywhere.com and I keep getting this:

{error : {'code': 214, 'message': 'Non-200 response code during CRC GET request (i.e. 404, 500, etc).'}}

In my wsgi configuration the code goes as follows

```
# This file contains the WSGI configuration required to serve up your
# web application at http://<your-username>.pythonanywhere.com/
# It works by setting the variable 'application' to a WSGI handler of some
# description.
#
# The below has been auto-generated for your Flask project

import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = '/home/YouMatterBot2/mysite'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from flask_app import app as application  # noqa
```

Here's the code in the flask_app.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory, make_response
from http import HTTPStatus

import Twitter, hashlib, hmac, base64, os, logging, json

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('.env')

CONSUMER_SECRET = os.getenv('CONSUMER_SECRET')
CURRENT_USER_ID = os.getenv('CURRENT_USER_ID')
         
app = Flask(__name__)   

#generic index route    
@app.route('/')
def default_route():        
    return send_from_directory('www', 'index.html')               

#The GET method for webhook should be used for the CRC check
#TODO: add header validation (compare_digest https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/hmac.html)
@app.route("/webhook", methods=["GET"])
def twitterCrcValidation():
    
    crc = request.args['crc_token']
  
    validation = hmac.new(
        key=bytes(CONSUMER_SECRET, 'utf-8'),
        msg=bytes(crc, 'utf-8'),
        digestmod = hashlib.sha256
    )
    digested = base64.b64encode(validation.digest())
    response = {
        'response_token': 'sha256=' + format(str(digested)[2:-1])
    }
    print('responding to CRC call')

    return json.dumps(response)   
        
#The POST method for webhook should be used for all other API events
#TODO: add event-specific behaviours beyond Direct Message and Like
@app.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
def twitterEventReceived():
            
    requestJson = request.get_json()

    #dump to console for debugging purposes
    print(json.dumps(requestJson, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
            
    if 'favorite_events' in requestJson.keys():
        #Tweet Favourite Event, process that
        likeObject = requestJson['favorite_events'][0]
        userId = likeObject.get('user', {}).get('id')          
              
        #event is from myself so ignore (Favourite event fires when you send a DM too)   
        if userId == CURRENT_USER_ID:
            return ('', HTTPStatus.OK)
            
        Twitter.processLikeEvent(likeObject)
                          
    elif 'direct_message_events' in requestJson.keys():
        #DM recieved, process that
        eventType = requestJson['direct_message_events'][0].get("type")
        messageObject = requestJson['direct_message_events'][0].get('message_create', {})
        messageSenderId = messageObject.get('sender_id')   
        
        #event type isnt new message so ignore
        if eventType != 'message_create':
            return ('', HTTPStatus.OK)
            
        #message is from myself so ignore (Message create fires when you send a DM too)   
        if messageSenderId == CURRENT_USER_ID:
            return ('', HTTPStatus.OK)
             
        Twitter.processDirectMessageEvent(messageObject)    
                
    else:
        #Event type not supported
        return ('', HTTPStatus.OK)
    
    return ('', HTTPStatus.OK)

                        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 65010.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 65010))
    gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
    app.logger.handlers = gunicorn_logger.handlers
    app.logger.setLevel(gunicorn_logger.level)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

but when I run the this code to register my webhook

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env')

CONSUMER_KEY = os.getenv('CONSUMER_KEY')
CONSUMER_SECRET = os.getenv('CONSUMER_SECRET')

ACCESS_TOKEN = os.getenv('ACCESS_TOKEN')
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = os.getenv('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')

#The environment name for the beta is filled below. Will need changing in future        
ENVNAME = os.getenv('ENVNAME')
WEBHOOK_URL = os.getenv('WEBHOOK_URL')

twitterAPI = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

r = twitterAPI.request('account_activity/all/:%s/webhooks' % ENVNAME, {'url': WEBHOOK_URL})

print (r.status_code)
print(r.json())
print (r.text)
```

I get the said error.

Is this a problem because of pythonanywhere.com, if so how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the code that you're running to handle requests to `https://YouMatterBot2.pythonanywhere.com/twitter/callback`?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, but I used another repository in making my app. But it still returned the same error code.

Comment: I've updated the code just now!

Comment: Thanks!  In your original post you said that you were specifying `https://YouMatterBot2.pythonanywhere.com/twitter/callback`.  In your updated code, you're using the URL that is in the environment variable `WEBHOOK_URL` instead, but I'll assume that that environment variable is set to the URL that you originally had.  If that's the case, then the problem is that your Flask site does not specify a route for that URL -- you've defined `/webhook` instead of `/twitter/callback`.

Comment: I fixed that URL issue, and it's now listening at /webhook but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: from my error server log I'm getting,                                  
key=bytes(CONSUMER_SECRET, 'utf-8'),
TypeError: encoding without a string argument , How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you add the full stack trace to your question?